# file not found while chaining multiple map-reduce hadoop java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to execute two map-reduces, but the second map-reduce can not find the middle outputs
here is my driver code:

```java
public class driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job1 = Job.getInstance(conf, "find_click_patterns");
        job1.setJarByClass(driver.class);
        job1.setMapperClass(Map1.class);
        job1.setReducerClass(Reduce1.class);

        job1.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job1.setOutputKeyClass(QueryResultWritable.class);
        job1.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job1.setMapOutputValueClass(ListWritable.class);

        Path destinationDir = new Path(args[1]);
        TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]));
        Path middle_output = destinationDir.suffix("/_1");
        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, middle_output);

        job1.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.out.println("Job 1 completed");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        System.out.println("if middle output exists: "+fs.exists(middle_output));
        System.out.println("middle output: "+middle_output);

        Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();
        Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2, "count_click_patterns_per_query_result");
        job2.setJarByClass(driver.class);
        job2.setMapperClass(Map2.class);
        job2.setReducerClass(Reduce2.class);

        job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(TripleWritable.class);
        job2.setMapOutputValueClass(clickPatternWritable.class);


        Path p = new Path("/home/kasra/Documents/khaje/Term3/BigData/HW3/Q33/output_tmp/_1");
        TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, p);
        // same error here:
        //TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, middle_output);
        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, destinationDir.suffix("/_2"));


        System.out.println("if middle output exists: "+fs.exists(p));
        System.out.println("middle output: "+p);
        System.exit(job2.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);


    }
}
```

and my args are: `../yandex/ output_tmp`

the first map-reduce runs successfully, but the second map-reduce throws this error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/kasra/Documents/khaje/Term3/BigData/HW3/Q33/output_tmp/_1
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1568)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1589)
    at driver.main(driver.java:55)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/kasra/Documents/khaje/Term3/BigData/HW3/Q33/output_tmp/_1
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    ... 13 more
```

also, the output of `fs.exists(middle_output)` is true, and the files are available

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: You shouldn't need two jobs. Look at the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs` class. Other than that, do you really need mapreduce? I suspect using Spark would have less setup code

Comment: I need to do more computations on the first map-reduce jobs, so I need two jobs. And unfortunately, it's a university project, and I SHOULD solve the question using map-reduce.

Comment: Your issue seems to be the error shows a local filesystem path `/home/kasra/`. Meanwhile, the first reducer output (and next mapper input) should be an **HDFS path**, which would start with `hdfs://` where there is a `/user` path, not `/home`, rather than `file://`... This would imply that your `core-site.xml` file doesn't properly set `default.FS` to the hdfs path and is using the default local filesystem when you create `new Configuration`

Comment: if I run the code directly using java I can use a local address, but if I run the jar file using Hadoop It needs to be an hdfs address, anyway, the problem remains the same while using Hadoop.@OneCricketeer

Comment: Hadoop can use both local `file://` and `hdfs://` URIs, and it can be ran "directly using Java", so I dont understand what you mean. I told you that that's the problem. You appear to be wanting to run the code in a cluster (or remote Hadoop environment), where **there is no `/home/kasra` folder**), so you should not hard-code that path in your code.

Comment: Oh, I see. Check out the `midddle_output` variable. The first job's output is in the `middle_output,` and I have the same problem using this variable.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `../` relative paths, either. The input data should be available on HDFS after you use `hdfs put`. Then you give the absolute HDFS path to Hadoop Path object